# ¿Por qué al poner el campo de mi base de datos como timestamp no se ingresa la fecha actual?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, vb.net

mi campo 'fecha' en vez de traer la fecha actual aparece esto:
[image: campo fecha de tipo timestamp]

¿cómo lo puedo solucionar? o si hay otra forma de obtener la fecha actual y que se almacene en la base de datos al momento de enviar el formulario 
agradecería sus respuestas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tipo de datos `timestamp` de SQL Server no almacena fechas y horas, sino que es un sinónimo del tipo [`rowversion`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), que es básicamente un *contador* interno de la base de datos, que tiene garantía de ser único, y que cambia automáticamente con cada `update` que se le haga a cualquier fila. Está, además, marcado como obsoleto.

Si lo que quieres es almacenar la fecha y hora a la que se creó el registro, utiliza una columna de tipo `datetime` o `datetime2`, que puede tener un `default` con la función `getDate()`.

Por ejemplo, la creación de tu tabla podría ser algo como:

```
create table MiTabla (
  MiID      int not null primary key
  Fecha     datetime not null default getDate()
);
```

Para que la columna tome siempre el `getDate()` que tiene como default debes asegurarte de **no** incluirla dentro de tu sentencia insert:

```
insert into MiTabla (MiID) values (1);
```